# Pythn split an excel sheet to multiple pdf files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pdf

I have a single excel worksheet that I would like to split into multiple **pdf** files, using python.
To save to multiple excel files I have used a code like below, but not sure how to modify it for a pdf output. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.read_excel('./data_1.xlsx')
grouped_df = data_df.groupby('columnA')

for data in grouped_df.displayName:
    grouped_df.get_group(data[0]).to_excel("./IO/Files/"+data[0]+".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

data_df = pd.read_excel('./data_1.xlsx')
grouped_df = data_df.groupby('columnA')

for data in grouped_df.displayName:
    temp_df = grouped_df.get_group(data[0])
    temp_df.to_excel("./IO/Files/"+data[0]+".xlsx")
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.table(cellText=tmp_df.values,colLabels=tmp_df.columns,loc='center')
    pp = PdfPages("./IO/Files/"+ data[0] + ".pdf")
    pp.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
    pp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked nicely :) I only had to change the figsize for A4 format :) thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote answers to your question and please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your issue.